# Extract a ZIP file programmatically by DotNetZip library?

Tags: c#, zip, extract, dotnetzip

I have a function that get a ZIP file and extract it to a directory
(I use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) library.)

```
public void ExtractFileToDirectory(string zipFileName, string outputDirectory)
{
     ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipFileName);
     Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDirectory);
     zip.ExtractAll(outputDirectory,ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
}
```

My ZIP file contains multiple files and directories. But I want to extract only 
some of these files, not all of them.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to test each [ZipEntry](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DotNetZipHelp/html/6c55db80-ec01-c606-be38-2ea91a64df15.htm) to see if you want to extract it:

```
public void ExtractFileToDirectory(string zipFileName, string outputDirectory)
{
     ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipFileName);
     Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDirectory);
      foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
      {
        // check if you want to extract e or not
        if(e.FileName == "TheFileToExtract") 
          e.Extract(outputDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

There is a ExtractSelectedEntries method in ZipFile class. here's the method signature.

```
public void ExtractSelectedEntries(string selectionCriteria, string directoryPathInArchive, string extractDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction extractExistingFile)
```

So in your program, you can simply extract the specified files by providing the selectionCriteria.

```
public void ExtractFileToDirectory(string zipFileName, string outputDirectory)
{
     ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipFileName);
     Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDirectory);
     zip.ExtractSelectedEntries("name = *.doc", "document\", outputDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
}
```

You can combine criteria with the conjunctions AND or OR. Using a string like "name = *.txt AND size >= 100k" for the selectionCriteria retrieves entries whose names end in .txt, and whose uncompressed size is greater than or equal to 100 kilobytes.

here are some criteria samples

---

**criteria (Files retrieved)**

name != *.xls (any file with an extension that is not .xls)

name = *.mp3 (any file with a .mp3 extension)

*.mp3 (same as above, any file with a .mp3 extension)

attributes = A (all files whose attributes include the Archive bit)

attributes != H (all files whose attributes do not include the Hidden bit)

mtime > 2009-01-01 (all files with a last modified time after January 1st, 2009)

size > 2gb (all files whose uncompressed size is greater than 2gb)

---

For more reference, you should read the API document alone with the library.

Comment: How to use ExtractSelectedEntries with multiple criteria. I need it for all the image formats(jpg,png,gif,jpeg) . How to do it?

Answer (score 14):

You can also use LINQ to select which entries you want to extract.  For example:

```
using (var zip = ZipFile.Read(ArchiveToRead))
{
    var selection = from e in zip.Entries
        where System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.FileName).StartsWith("C")
        select e;

    foreach (var e in selection)
        e.Extract(extractDir);
}
```

Of course you can use whatever query criteria you want in the `where` clause.