# Auto Extract a zip file

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I'm trying make a program that extracts a specific zip file everytime the program launches.

this is my code to create the zip file:

```
//creating the file
ZipFile File = new ZipFile(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\ABCD.zip");

//Adding files

File.AddFile(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\ab.dat", "");
File.AddFile(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\cd.dat", "");

//Save the file
File.Save();
```

I want to Extract the files **ab.dat** and **cd.dat** from ABCD.zip to the .exe file directory automatically.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324626/extract-a-zip-file-programmatically-by-dotnetzip-library?rq=1, this is not helping ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken mostly from the [DotNetZip documentation](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples):

```
private void Extract()
{
    //Zip Location
    string zipToUnpack = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\ABCD.zip";
    // .EXE Directory
    string unpackDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipToUnpack))
    {
        foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
        {
             //If filename matches
             if (e.FileName == "ab.dat" || e.FileName == "cd.dat")
                 e.Extract(unpackDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also filter the results using `ExtractSelectEntries` by selecting the files there:

```
zip.ExtractSelectedEntries("name = 'ab.dat' OR name = 'cd.dat'", "\", unpackDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently)
```

Or selecting all `.dat` files with a wildcard

```
zip.ExtractSelectedEntries("name = '*.dat'", "\", unpackDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently)
```

Use each `ZipEntry`'s `FileName` property to see if it has the name you would like to extract.